# android query failed com.android.internal.telephonyCommandException RADIO_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: android, mobile, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

After upgrading from ICS 4.0.4 to 4.0.6 my mobile won't get any connection via radio. WiFi just great, no problems there. In Settings even the SIM-Settings are blacked out. IMEI just okay, checked that.

When checking the band mode I got the error message: `Query failed` AND `com.android.internal.telephonyCommandException : RADIO_NOT_AVAILABLE`.

Anyone any guess how to fix THIS mess?